# Move modules from vendor to app

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer

We've took over a Magento2 store which is using several (payed) modules without a working license key which wont be provided by the previous agency. The modules are created by the previous agency, so there isn't an option to get a working license key.

Since the modules are part of the composer package, I'm unable to use composer to update and therefore unable to update Magento.

Is there a way to move the modules from vendor, remove then from composer and moving them to app/code? Without the modules the shop can't be used since it's part of the theme.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the modules from your vendor to a backup folder outside of your magento installation.
Also backup your composer.lock & composer.json just to be sure, so if anything goes wrong, you can just put it all back.

Remove the modules with composer.

Then create folders like this in your app/code/vendorname/modulename. You can find the correct names in the registration.php's from these modules (vendor_module).

Usually the composer packages have their content in a vendor/module/src folder. Just copy the content over to the newly created folders.

Now your composer module is an app code module.

Note: These modules might be incompatible if you update your magento installation.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.